# Slick Code generation always looks for Tables.scala file. WHY?

Tags: scala, sbt, slick

I am just starting to use slick and i need to generate schema from my existing database.

I looked around at slicks code generator and checked out some examples online (which all look the same and generate the same error BTW).

So to reference my code, here is the sample that I refer to:

https://gist.github.com/matanster/512fb33d67e7ddd7eb46

And it looks like this:

> ```
> slickGenerate := {
>   import java.io.File
>   val dbName = "mydb"
>   val userName = "mycomp"
>   val password = "1234"
>   val url = s"jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/$dbName" // adapt as necessary to your system
>   val jdbcDriver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" // replace if not MySQL
>   val slickDriver = "slick.driver.MySQLDriver" // replace if not MySQL
>   val resultRelativeDir = "model" // directory to create output scala slick definitions at
>   val targetPackageName = "com.pany.proj.model" // package name to give it
>   val resultFilePath = s"$resultRelativeDir/$targetPackageName/Tables.scala" // override the name if you like
>   val backupFilePath = s"$resultRelativeDir/$targetPackageName/Tables.scala.auto-backup" // override the name if you like
>   val format = scala.Console.BLUE + scala.Console.BOLD
>   println(format + s"Backing up existing slick mappings source to: file://${baseDirectory.value}/$backupFilePath")
>   println(format + s"About to auto-generate slick mappings source from database schema at $url...")
>   sbt.IO.copyFile(new File(resultFilePath), new File(backupFilePath))
>   (runner in Compile).value.run("slick.codegen.SourceCodeGenerator", (dependencyClasspath in Compile).value.files, Array(slickDriver, jdbcDriver, url, resultRelativeDir, targetPackageName, userName, password), streams.value.log)
>   println(format + s"Result: file://${baseDirectory.value}/$resultFilePath" + scala.Console.RESET)
>   val diff = (s"diff -u $resultFilePath $backupFilePath" #| "colordiff").!!
>   println(scala.Console.BLUE + s"Changes compared to previous output file, follow, if any.\n\n $diff")
>   Seq(file(resultFilePath))
> }
> ```

When running this code i always get the following error:

> ```
> Backing up existing slick mappings source to: file:///Users/me/Documents/views/proj/model/com.pany.proj.model/Tables.scala.auto-backup
> About to auto-generate slick mappings source from database schema at jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/pany...
> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: Source file '/Users/me/Documents/views/proj/model/com.pany.proj.model/Tables.scala' does not exist.
> at scala.Predef$.require(Predef.scala:233)
> at sbt.IO$.copyFile(IO.scala:636)
> at $802a1e7ec0732f92084d$$anonfun$$sbtdef$1.apply(/Users/me/Documents/views/proj/build.sbt:60)
> at $802a1e7ec0732f92084d$$anonfun$$sbtdef$1.apply(/Users/me/Documents/views/proj/build.sbt:45)
> at scala.Function1$$anonfun$compose$1.apply(Function1.scala:47)
> at sbt.$tilde$greater$$anonfun$$u2219$1.apply(TypeFunctions.scala:40)
> at sbt.std.Transform$$anon$4.work(System.scala:63)
> at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:228)
> at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:228)
> at sbt.ErrorHandling$.wideConvert(ErrorHandling.scala:17)
> at sbt.Execute.work(Execute.scala:237)
> at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:228)
> at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:228)
> at sbt.ConcurrentRestrictions$$anon$4$$anonfun$1.apply(ConcurrentRestrictions.scala:159)
> at sbt.CompletionService$$anon$2.call(CompletionService.scala:28)
> at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
> at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
> at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
> at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
> at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
> at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
> [error] (*:slickGenerate) java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: Source file '/Users/me/Documents/views/proj/model/com.pany.proj.model/Tables.scala' does not exist.
> [error] Total time: 0 s, completed May 23, 2016 3:04:59 PM
> ```

Which is really frustrating because i was under the impression that the code generator is supposed to generate the code?! So what am i doing wrong.

As well I cant figure out the `dir` and `package name` things. it looks wired and unrelated to what its trying to accomplish.

Comment: `resultFilePath` and `backupFilePath` should contain slashes instead of dots to separate the package segments.

Comment: That actually worked in solving the problem. Thanks